# Is it possible to have Definitions as sub-definitions in JSON-Schema (Draft 0.7)

Tags: json, jsonschema

Ok So been using JSON for a long time new to JSON-Schema but im trying to work out if it's possible to have nested definitions?

**What i mean:** i want to be able to use `"$ref":"#definitions/link/post"` & `"$ref":"#definitions/link/default"` there post is defined under link.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "id":"https://api.thisisbeacon.com/schemas/",
    "definitions":{
        "link":{
            "default":{
                "$ref":"link/single.schema.json"
            },
            "post":{
                "$ref":"link/post/single.schema.json"
            }
        },
    },
    "$ref":"#definitions/link/post"
}
```

And I'm using a test json that is a valid

```
{
    "$schema":"https://api.thisisbeacon.com/schemas/link/post/single.schema.json",
    "url":"http://www.google.com",
    "post":1,
    "channnel":"testing"
}
```

I'm testing the schema on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Now the `"$ref":"#definitions/link/default"` a the bottom of a schema is purely for testing with, in a real system it won't ever have any actual formatting rules in it only the definitions but my aim is to have it so all any client-side developer can test with

```
{ 
    "id":"https://api.thisisbeacon.com/schemas/", 
    "$ref":"schema.json#/definitions/{the_definition_to_test_with}" 
}
```

Where in my test example i would have `{the_definition_to_test_with} = link/post`

Comment: Have you tried it and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah i said i tested the schema on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/, and it gives 

`Could not resolve schema reference 'https://api.thisisbeacon.com/schemas/schema.json#/definitions/link/default'. Path '', line 1, position 1.`

Comment: OK. Have you read http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.9 ?

Comment: i read, `http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html`

Comment: You didn't include the error message in your question (which you should do).

Comment: What do you understand when you read the section I have linked you to?

Comment: That it's using a single layer definition, it's ok after reading all of the schema's I worked it out. But you're not subtly and patronisingly method of trying to get me to work out on my own.
So instead of answering and citing your sources like I oh I don't know the point of Stack Overflow. as it is last night I worked out a possible method I just need to test it before marking it as the answer if someone could get closer to what wanted and not what I have, they would have helped inform me better... and rightly be awarded the answer

Comment: Sorry Martin. I was trying to be helpful by showing you where to find your answer. The point of Stack Overflow is for when you've already done the research and you feel you understand the docs and it still doesn't work as expected. I wasn't sure if the docs explained it sufficiently, or if you found the right docs. If not, then we need to update it. I'm happy to offer further help (and others will be to) if you want to join the JSON Schema Slack, link found on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after working with the JSON-Schema team it turns out that my setup was correct for my nodes, my test case of `"$ref":"#definitions/link/post"` is what was causing the problem it was overwriting the definitions that were created in the same file.

`"allOf":{"$ref":"#definitions/link/definitions/post/definitions/single"}`